# AngularJS assign variables to view's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-scope

I have a somewhat deep JSON object I am trying to using in an HTML template.

```
{
    "service": {
        "name": "example",
        "url": "abc.com",
        "template": "/abc/def/v1",
        "metadata": {
            "password": "dontguessme",
            "username": "supereasy"
        }
    }
}
```

I am including a template with the following HTML code.

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-include="service.instructionsTemplate"> </div>
```

In the template there is the following.

```
<h1>Some example content</h1>
{{service.metadata.password}}
```

My question is instead of referencing the field password via service.metadata, is there a way I can reference it with just the variable password.

I was trying to dig through some of the Angular docs around scoping and templates but came up empty.  I saw you can use ng-init.

I was able to use `ng-init="metadata = service.metadata"` and was able to reference the field password in the template via `metadata.password`.
However I would just like to reference it by `password`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already did `ng-init="metadata = service.metadata"`, why not going a step further and do `ng-init="password = service.metadata.password"`?

Another way would be to bind `$scope.password =  service.metadata.password` inside the controller thayou're using on that page

---

**Edit:** OP asked a more general solution

If you don't know the property names, then your best move would be to bind the metadata object, like you already did, and then iterate through its properties using `ng-repeat`

in your controller:

```
$scope.metadata = service.metadata
```

in your template (view):

```
<h1>Some example content</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="element in metadata">{{element}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That would work however, the fields under metadata are not known, they could be any variable.  I was trying to come up with a solution that would work for unknown field names under service.metadata.

Comment: If you don't know their names, how are you gonna call them in the view?

Comment: What do you think of this more general solution?

Comment: The view content editor's (project managers) can edit content, but outside the view they can not.  I was trying to make a simple elegant way for content editor's to edit view's without using the full reference of the object they needed, ex. service.metadata.password.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set the password to something inside the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.data = {
    "service": {
        "name": "example",
        "url": "abc.com",
        "template": "/abc/def/v1",
        "metadata": {
            "password": "dontguessme",
            "username": "supereasy"
        }
    }
};

$scope.password = $scope.data.service.metadata.password;

});
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/KrKeLIP2ANd0rl5NLywF?p=preview

Comment: I was trying to do this without hardcoding fields in the service.metadata object.  I did some more digging and from what I saw it doesn't seem quite possible....

Comment: What do you mean by not hard coding fields?  It isn't quite obvious what you are asking.  Maybe you want something like `$scope.password = getPassword(data)` ?